# AFNetworking Connection Detection and return a variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, afnetworking, httpconnection

I am using AFNetworking to detect the network connection for an iOS mobile app.

I am able to detect the connection however I want to return a variable so I can use that variable to do different action. 
I am using `setReachabilityStatusChange` but it is a void function. Is there any ways I can return a variable? Here is my code so far:

```
    class func CheckRechability() -> String {
    var networkStatus : String = ""

    AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().setReachabilityStatusChange {  (status: AFNetworkReachabilityStatus) in
        debugPrint(status.rawValue)

        switch (status.rawValue){
        case 0,-1:
            networkStatus = "notConnect"
            print("No rechability")
            break

        case 1,2:
            networkStatus = "connect"
            print("I have rechability")
            break

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().startMonitoring()
    return (networkStatus)
}
```

Nothing is returning the above code.
Or is there any way to get a callback through `AFNetworking` when it is connected to the network.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The setReachabilityStatusChange is an asynchronous block and it will be triggered whenever there are changes to the network status. In your current code, you will always get an empty string.  If you want to get the current status of the shared manager, I suggest initialising it from the AppDelegate and just using the isReachable property of AFNetworkReachabilityManager.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().startMonitoring()
}
```

...

```
func checkNetworkStatus() -> String  {
    var networkStatus : String = ""

    if AFNetworkReachabilityManager.shared().isReachable {
      networkStatus = "connect"
    }
    else {
      networkStatus = "notConnect"
    }

    return networkStatus
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it seems that it always return notConnect. I have changed to use "ReachabilitySwift" Library. Seems working even though I am still facing some other problems. But thanks a lot for your input!